# When using streams do you need to sync after cudamalloc

Tags: c++, cuda

When using streams in cuda, is it necessary to perform any synchronization between memory allocations and usage of this memory by a stream (assuming cudaMallocAsync is not available, which it is not for me).

example:

```
cudaStream_t stream;
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
... Other code

int *a;
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **)&a, sizeof(int)));
foo<<<1, 1, 0, stream>>>(a);
gpuErrchk(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
cudafree(a);
```

Is there a chance that when calling foo in such a situation, that the memory allocation is not completed?

Would I be forced to do a device synchronize after the allocation to be sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no chance that the memory allocation will not be completed.  You don't need an explicit device synchronization after a memory allocation.

When the `cudaMalloc` call returns, the memory is allocated and usable.

Comment: No I don't know why it was downvoted.  However, by studying CUDA codes (such as sample codes from NVIDIA, or codes presented here on the `cuda` SO tag) the answer to your question is evident.  The tooltip help for the downvote button includes this excerpt: "This question does not show any research effort"